# Adding data to a RecyclerView list item from a Dialog

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-alertdialog

I'm trying to get the data that user enters in a Dialog and place that data into the Text fields in my custom list item that I created for my RecyclerView.  This is my implementation:

```
public class AssignmentActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ...

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_assignment);

        ...

        FloatingActionButton assignmentAddButton = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.assignment_add_button);

        assignmentAddButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                editCourseInfoDialog();
            }
        });

    }

    private void editCourseInfoDialog() {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(AssignmentActivity.this);
        View dialogLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.assignment_edit_dialog, null);
        AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(AssignmentActivity.this);
        dialog.setView(dialogLayout);

        final TextView name = (TextView) dialogLayout.findViewById(R.id.assignmentNameView);
        final TextView mark = (TextView) dialogLayout.findViewById(R.id.assignmentMarkView);
        final TextView overallMark = (TextView) dialogLayout.findViewById(R.id.assignmentOverallMarkView);
        final TextView weight = (TextView) dialogLayout.findViewById(R.id.assignmentWeightView);

        dialog.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                assignment.setName(String.valueOf(name.getText()));
                assignment.setMark(Double.valueOf(mark.getText() + ""));
                assignment.setMarkOutOf(Double.valueOf(overallMark.getText() + ""));
                assignment.setPercentage(Double.valueOf(weight.getText() + ""));
                assignmentAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        dialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });
        dialog.show();
    }
}
```

The problem with this is that when I click OK, the dialog closes and all the data is destroyed.  I couldn't find a way to paste this data into the list-item because each attempt results in them getting lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [RxJAVA](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava) and [RxBindings](https://github.com/JakeWharton/RxBinding). It'll make everything much easier.

- Create function which returns Observable
- Show dialog inside of function
- When dialog completed call observable.onNext()

    -
- Subscribe that function (using fn().subscribe(...))
- Catch value inside of subscribe function
- Add it to your recyclerview

Comment: Buddy I'm very alien to RxJava.  Can we stick to standard Java with this?

Comment: You may assign data to member variable or use interfaces.

Comment: Yea but that data would be destroyed the moment the Alert Dialog is cancelled and the Text fields will still be empty.